# Reselect and recursive selector

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

I have a redux state with a tree of items (normalized) like:

```
state = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, parent: null, children: [2, 3] },
    { id: 2, parent: 1, children: [4] },
    { id: 3, parent: 1, children: [], value: 10 },
    { id: 4, parent: 2, children: [], value: 20 }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the reduce sum of values for item 1 (here = 10 + 20 = 30), and I want to create a reselect selector for that.

But, how can I define a recursive selector ?

Thanks for your help. ;-)

Frédéric

Comment: what do you mean with "create a reselect selector" ?

Comment: I mean to memoize the result of the "getter" from the state with: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Answer (score 2):

I'll update @Vanojx1 code to propose 2 solutions:

- with [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) only
- with [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) + [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) (to keep memoization when provided `id` changes)

*(Disclaimer: I'm the author of re-reselect, but this is a tipical use-case)*

## Base code

```
let state = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, parent: null, children: [2, 3] },
        { id: 2, parent: 1, children: [4] },
        { id: 3, parent: 1, children: [], value: 10 },
        { id: 4, parent: 2, children: [], value: 20 }
    ]
};

function getSum(items, id) {
  let item = items.find(item => item.id == id);
  return item.hasOwnProperty('value') ? item.value : item.children.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current + getSum(items, next);
  }, 0);
}
```

## Solution 1 - reselect only

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getSumSelector = createSelector(
  (state) => state.items,
  (state, id) => id,
  (items, id) => getSum(items, id)
);

getSumSelector(state, 1);
// Loses memoization with sequentials calls with same items but different id's
```

## Solution 2 - reselect + re-reselect

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';

const getSumSelector = createCachedSelector(
    state => state.items,
    (state, id) => id,
    (items, id) => getSum(items, id)
)(
    // Cache selector by id
    (state, id) => id
);

getSumSelector(state, 1);
```

Comment: thanks; with your solution, I have a question: when the tree is changed, is the selector updated too?

Comment: Selectors are pure functions and you have to pass the required arguments on each call. Please note that `reselect` default memoization will just do an equality check to tell if arguments are the same of the last call (`previousState` === `providedState`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let state = {
    items: [
        { id: 1, parent: null, children: [2, 3] },
        { id: 2, parent: 1, children: [4] },
        { id: 3, parent: 1, children: [], value: 10 },
        { id: 4, parent: 2, children: [], value: 20 }
    ]
}

function getSum(state, id) {
  let item = state.items.find(item => item.id == id);
  return item.hasOwnProperty('value') ? item.value : item.children.reduce((current, next) => {
    return current + getSum(state, next);
  }, 0);
}

let sum = getSum(state, 1);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I would like to use reselect with redux to memoize the result AND to reset the cache when one item value in the tree is updated